# Is there a way to "add" a Protocol to an already created python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, static-analysis, typing

I'm working on a libriary that defines a class decorator `addMethod` which adds `added_method` to the class. A simpified example:

```py
from my_lib import addMethod

@addMethod
class UserClass:
    pass
```

As a developer, I want the lib to be as convenient as possible, so the static analyzer has to "know" that UserClass has the `added_method`. I guess it can be achieved using python3.8 `typing.Protocol`, but the only examples I found demostraited using of `Protocol` on class defining, not after. Not sure whether it is really possible. But if it is, what is the best way?

Comment: Why are you using a decorator instead of a mix-in class?